# how can executorService store result of task `i` in `array[i]`?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, list, concurrency

I read this [post](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=247) about `executorService`

I want to fill a fixed size collection of results when order matters.

I could fill an array, when I know task `i` should store its result in `array[i]`.

Is there another built-in way to store results in the order the tasks were submitted? And can I fill a list instead of an array?

Comment: You have n tasks and you need parallel execution to calculate each task's result, but need the results in the same order as the tasks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Executors.invokeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)) method. From the javadocs:

> Parameters:
>
> tasks - the collection of tasks
>
> Returns:
>
> A list of Futures representing the tasks, in the same sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list, each of which has completed.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(SOME_SIZE);

Collection<Callable<T>> tasks = ...; // fill collection with callable tasks

List<Future<T>> futures = executor.invokeAll(tasks);
```

`invokeAll()` returns when all submitted tasks have finished their execution.

Then iterate over the returned futures and invoke `get()` on each one of them:

```
List<T> results = 
    futures.stream().map(Future::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Order of results will match that one of `tasks` collection.

In a one-liner:

```
List<T> results = 
    executor.invokeAll(tasks).stream().map(Future::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply store the `Future`s returned by `submit()` in an array or list, and then iterate over this list and call `get()` on each future:

```
List<Callable<Result>> tasks = ...;
List<Future<Result>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (Callable<Result> task : tasks) {
    futures.add(executor.submit(task));
}

List<Result> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (Future<Result> future : futures) {
    results.add(future.get());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the results from `Future` objects to a list in the same order as they were created:

```
// given some tasks and an executor 
List<Callable<MyResult>> tasks;
ExecutorService exec;

List<MyResult> results = exec.invokeAll(tasks).stream()
  .map(Future::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Will this execute concurrently? It is my understanding that a stream is iterated over only once, combining all stream operations. This would call Future.get right after submitting, causing serial execution.

Comment: @meriton this would call Future/get() serially, but that doesn't mean that the tasks aren't executed in parallel. Only that their result is collected serially. It's basically a Java8 version of the code in my answer.

Comment: @meriton the [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) method of Collection returns a *sequential* stream, whereas the [`parallelStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--) method returns a *parallel* one: My code will preserve order.

Comment: My concern is not that Future.get is invoked sequentially. My concern is that Future.get is invoked *before the remaining tasks have been submitted*, because a stream collapses all map operations. That is, if we execute `Arrays.asList(1,2,3).stream().map(print("S")).map(print("G")).collect(Collectors.toList());` we get the output `SGSGSG`, not `SSSGGG` as would be needed for parallel execution.

Comment: @meriton that's an interesting point, but there's nothing in the question to suggest that the result of one task is affected by the execution/submission or not of another task. Such a situation would suggest the tasks are not suitable for parallel processing, since execution order via an Executor is not-determinant. The OP clearly intends using an Executor, so we must assume execution order, and by implication submission order, is irrelevant.

Comment: @Bohemian Now I understand what meriton means. And indeed, this would lead to f1 = submit(task1); f1.get(); f2 = submit(task2); f2.get(); etc. leading to serial execution of tasks: task 2 would only start executing after task 1 has completed.

Comment: @JBNizet right.So, would that edit fix it? Is there a better way - it looks a bit silly now.

Comment: @jbn doh! Found a better way using `invokeAll()` (can't believe I didn't think of that earlier). You may consider amending your (java 7) answer to use `invokeAll()` too to eliminate your first loop, ie `for (Future<Result> future : executor.invokeAll(tasks)) ...`. Cheers